# MySQL error Greatest-n-per-group

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

```
    SELECT ma_forum.*, ma_forum_cat.*
    FROM ma_forum, ma_forum_cat
    JOIN ma_forum_comentarios ON ma_forum_comentarios.not_id = ma_forum.not_id
    WHERE ma_forum.notcat_id=ma_forum_cat.notcat_id AND ma_forum.notcat_id='".$notcat_id."' 
    AND ma_forum.not_status='Ativo'
    GROUP BY ma_forum.not_id
    ORDER BY MAX(ma_forum_comentarios.comnot_data) DESC
```

Unknown column 'ma_forum.not_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: The column does not exist in the table that table alias `ma_forum` represents.  There's no information for us to help you beyond that.

Comment: Stop mixing implicit (comma-separated tables) and explicit joins.  You're using two inner joins, so use two proper `JOIN`s and remove the first implicit join condition from your WHERE clause

Comment: This is kind of a duplicate of your other question. Same topic. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555413/order-by-in-other-table#comment16910497_12555413

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column `not_id` does not exist in the `ma_forum` table.

If the column does exist, try the following and report back.

```
SELECT ma_forum.*, 
       ma_forum_cat.*
FROM   ma_forum JOIN 
       ma_forum_cat ON ma_forum.notcat_id = ma_forum_cat.notcat_id JOIN 
       ma_forum_comentarios ON ma_forum_comentarios.not_id = ma_forum.not_id
WHERE  ma_forum.notcat_id = '$notcat_id' AND 
       ma_forum.not_status= 'Ativo'
GROUP BY ma_forum.not_id
ORDER BY MAX(ma_forum_comentarios.comnot_data) DESC
```